# How to save a QIcon in a settings.ini using QSettings?

Tags: qt, qsettings, qicon

I'm trying to save a QIcon in a settings.ini using QSettings.

I'm saving the icon this way:

```
   QIcon icon = button->icon();
   if (!icon.isNull())
      iniSettings->setValue("icon", icon.pixmap(32, 32).toImage());
```

And trying to load it as:

```
   qDebug() << iniSettings->value("icon");
   QIcon icon = iniSettings->value("icon").value<QIcon>();
   if (!icon.isNull())
      button->setIcon(icon);
```

But icon is NULL, whats wrong?

Comment: Save `QPixmap` instead `QImage`, then reading QIcon may work because Qt has `QIcon(const QPixmap&)` constructor. If you stay with saving QImage, to create QIcon you should do the following: read QImage from QSettings, then create QPixmap by `QPixmap::fromImage` and create QIcon by `QIcon(const QPixmap&)`.